# complete Keras Lambda confusion

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to define a Lambda layer Keras, as follows:

First, a function which computes the wavelet transform of an image and then gloms it together:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K
import pywt
import numpy as np
from keras.engine.topology import Layer

def mkwtarray(image):
    channels = K.image_data_format()
    if channels is 'channels_first':
        axbase = 1
    else:
        axbase = 0
    print(axbase)
    print(image.shape)
    (a,( b, c, d ))= pywt.dwt2(image, 'db1', axes=(axbase, axbase+1))
    ab = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=axbase)
    cd = np.concatenate((c, d), axis=axbase)
    abcd = np.concatenate((ab, cd), axis=axbase+1)
    return abcd

def wtoutshape(input_shape):
    return input_shape

train_data_dir = 'train'
validation_data_dir = 'validation'
nb_train_samples = 21558
nb_validation_samples = 3446
epochs = 30
batch_size = 32

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(mkwtarray, input_shape=input_shape, output_shape = wtoutshape))
<more random  layers>
```

Much to my amazement, as I was defining the model (meaning, evaluated the lines above), it errored out, claiming:
    ValueError: Input array has fewer dimensions than the specified axes

Also, the 'print' statements, which printed the expected values `0` and `(?, 150, 150, 3)` fired, which means that the function was actually evaluated at definition time, not when the model was actually running. I am obviously missing something about Keras' Lambda functionality - any enlightenment would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** The exact same problem presents itself if you define a layer in the "general" way (via a class, where the lambda is now in the call function of the layer, so this is not lambda-specific.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You have a bigger problem, you can't implement a lambda layer using numpy or other non-backend functions. Backpropagation through your layer won't work at all, you have to use keras.backend functions.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am not sure it is a BIGGER problem, it is a different (and, I agree, fatal, for this little experiment) problem, but the point of my post was that this behavior makes no semantic sense to me: it seems akin to a text editor plugging completely  random objects into functions I am writing - figuring out what is going on might make future projects less painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a disastrous mix of NumPy and Keras. Let's look at the 2 main confusion points:

1. Once you are inside a Keras model, example Lambda layer, you are dealing with **tensors** and *not* NumPy arrays. Although convinient it would be, you can't use any NumPy operations, external libraries inside models. Having said that, tensor operators are very similar to arrays for good reason. Because it's your first layer, you can *pre-process* it in NumPy and then pass that into your model, this would work.
2. Why you get prints working? There are 2 main steps in Keras, Tensorflow: 1-> build the computation graph, 2-> actually run it. So you are building the graph and your operations get called yes, but they create *symbolic* tensors that have no value. So you can print the shape which can be determined when building the graph but not for example the values it holds.

Take away message, don't mix NumPy with Tensorflow inside computation graphs (models) and by all means print the shapes while building the graph to get an idea of what the graph looks like but you won't get anything more out of symbolic tensors at build time.

Comment: Thanks. This is consistent with what I had conjectured  - that the "quoting" (delaying evaluation) is a tensorflow thing, so Keras does not need to to it itself, and I guess this is why there is no pytorch backend to Keras :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little late, but this week I've been having a similar problem and managed to solve it.

I stopped using lambda layers to fix the problem, instead I created my own layer.

You can see how it works in my *GitHub* or *Hugging Face* repository.

- GitHub: https://github.com/FernandoPerezLara/image-preprocessing-layer
- Hugging Face: https://huggingface.co/fernandoperlar/preprocessing_image

I hope it at least solves the problem for some future person.

/ Fernando